# Vault UI is not opening in browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, hashicorp-vault

My vault is deployed in EKS cluster with S3 backend but whenever I try to access UI in the browser it gives 404.

This is my values.yaml file

```
server:
    affinity: null
    dataStorage:
      enabled: false
    dev:
      enabled: false
    standalone:
      enabled: false
    ha:
      enabled: true
      replicas: 1

      config: |

        ui = true
        listener "tcp" {
          tls_disable = 1
          address = "[::]:8200"
          cluster_address = "[::]:8201"

        }

        storage "s3" {
          access_key = "key"
          secret_key = "key"
          bucket     = "name"
          region     = "region"
        }

ui:
  enabled: true
  serviceType: "LoadBalancer"
```

Comment: What URL are you trying to access?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP status Code 404 means that 404 is returned if the specified resource such as a vault, upload ID, or job ID does not exist.

Make sure that you have properly handled Vault - [vault-404](https://github.com/jenkins-x/jx/issues/5631).

Take a look: [404-http-code-amazon](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/api-error-responses.html).
Don't you have extraSecretEnvironmentVars ? Please fill proper field of file with proper values.
Add following block of code under server standalone section:

```
service:  
  enabled:  true
```

Look at: [standalone-service-vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/platform/k8s/helm/examples/standalone-load-balanced-ui).

Your  `values.json`  file should be in YAML format.  What is more important is that it's not even valid YAML, as it has a block of JSON plonked in the middle of it .

Look at the proper example here:  [vault-eks](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/platform/k8s/helm/run).

Answer (score 0):

It is solved I just have to put external Port for service

```
 enabled: true
  serviceType: "LoadBalancer"
  externalPort: 8200
```